# Best way to get response code with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, request

I'm building a web crawler and just added Selenium to the crawler, but i realized that it is not posible to get the http status code, without using request before Selenium.

I'm using Selenium because i need to get the page content after it has fully loaded the page.

So at the moment my crawler is doing its job like this.

```
1. Using request to get http status_code (Counts as 1 reqeust)
1.. Got response code (200,301,400)

2. Using Selenium to get page content (Counts as 1 reqeust)
2.. Got page content from Selenium
```

The issue is that I'm using 2 request to get the complete page content, is there anyway, maybe whit out using Selenium, where i can get the page and response code, but only by using 1 request?

Answer (score 0):

In quick words - getting `status code` from the `selenium webdriver API` currently it is not possible and will never be added to an API. https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/141

Comment: I do know it's not possible to get the status code from Selenium by itself, but its there better way of doing it without using Selenium?

Comment: @user3502250 the fastest and simplest method is to use `requests` library and make a simple condition `r = requests.get(url) if r.status_code == 200: self.webdriver = webdriver.Chrome() self.webdriver.get(url)`

Comment: That's what im doint today, but the Request call is 1 request and the webdriver.get() is another one, i whould like to only make 1 total request call, if you know what i mean ? :)

Comment: I told you in an answer - there is not possible to check that status with a selenium and it will never be - check the link that I have attached

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to do it without Selenium im asking for another way completely to do this, it doesn't need to be Selenium. So the answer didn't help me.

Comment: @user3502250 So I provided you an answer - the requests based condition lol. I dunno what you expect to do. If you want to grab the page content why don't you just write that code? `import requests r = requests.get(url) if r.status_code == 200 page_source = r.text`

Comment: Because the way you are suggesting cant get Javascript content, thats why i use Selenium at the moment.

Comment: so maybe the next time explain that in the question because I wanted to just help. Check for the library that provides the `JS render`

Comment: Sorry but what other reason is there to use Selenium? in a web crawler then to work with the page from javascript perspective?